# c# dataset gridview can't save data in table permanently

Tags: c#, gridview, save, addition, bindingnavigator

I'm making library system management, and I have 3 tables in one dataset. I made add, edit and remove buttons to add, edit and remove data from tables (plus rent and return buttons).

When I restart vs2012 data is still there, but when I restart computer, data is gone.

Even that BindingNavigator that gets added when I added the first table, can't save data permanently. So only way to permanently manage data is by selecting table in Sever Explorer, than clicking on Show Table Data, and go through data without debugging or processing any code. That data reapers after restarting computer, weather I deleted it later by delete button or not.

Here's the code:
This first one is save button for available books, and that code came with the first table I added, I didn't edit it at all.

```
 private void slobodne_KnjigeBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.slobodne_KnjigeBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.slobodneKnjigeDataSet);

        }
```

This second one is add button for new member to be added in members table.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.članoviBindingSource.AddNew();
        }
```

Third one is save button for members table.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.članoviBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager2.UpdateAll(this.clanoviDataSet);
        }
```

This forth one is remove for members.

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.članoviDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                this.članoviBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
            }


        }
```

I know people often ask this question, I tried all the suggestions, but I couldn't fix it.

Comment: UpdateAll will save only if no rules are violated. Put a try catch around it to see if it is not giving some error.

Comment: @David I tried it, the code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call `dataset.AcceptChanges()` to commit the changes to the database.

Comment: Seems like this is working. Although it worked few times even without that line of code, and than after another restart data was gone. I'll try it few more times. Thanks